# How to apply Chinese Reminder Theorem to this congruence system?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

\begin{align*}
17x & \equiv -15 \pmod{5}\\
-11x & \equiv 5 \pmod{3}\\
23x & \equiv 15 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}

$5$, $3$, $7$ are coprime, so the system has solution mod $105$.
I'm not sure about how to solve it. For CRT the $x$ coefficients must be $1$. 
How can I "simplify" this ?

Comment: I will not solve it for you, but first, you can start out by simplifying say $17$ and $15$ mod $5$, and simplifying the coefficients of the other equations as well. As a strategy, you can solve the problem in $2$ steps. First transform the first $2$ equations into a single congruence mod $15$. Then as a second step, consider also the $3rd$ equation. It is not so difficult. Good luck!

Comment: Make the coefficients $1$. For example $23x\equiv 15\pmod{7}$ is equivalent to $2x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, which is (multiply by $4$) equivalent to $x\equiv 4\pmod{7}$.

Comment: (I solved it in my head)

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $17 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ and $-15 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, the congruence $17x \equiv -15 \pmod{5}$ reduces to $2x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$, which implies $x \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ since each non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $-11 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $5 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, the congruence $-11x \equiv 5 \pmod{3}$ reduces to $x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Since $23 \equiv  2 \pmod{7}$ and $15 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, the congruence $23x \equiv 15 \pmod{7}$ reduces to $2x \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.  We can solve this congruence by applying the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).
\begin{align*}
7 & = 3 \cdot 2 + 1\\
2 & = 2 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
Solving for $1$ in terms of $7$ and $2$ yields
$$1 = 7 - 3 \cdot 2 \implies -3 \cdot 2 \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \implies 2^{-1} \equiv -3 \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$$
Multiplying both sides of the congruence $2x \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ by $4$ yields $x \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$, where we have used the fact that $8 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

Hence, the system of congruences
\begin{align*}
17x & \equiv -15 \pmod{5}\\
-11x & \equiv 5 \pmod{3}\\
23x & \equiv 15 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}
simplifies to 
\begin{align*}
x & \equiv 0 \pmod{5}\\
x & \equiv 2 \pmod{3}\\
x & \equiv 4 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

17x≡-15(mod5) is equivalent to 17x≡0(mod5) so x=5n 
-11x≡5(mod3) is equivalent to 11x≡-5(mod3)  or 11x≡1(mod3) 
23x≡15(mod7) is equivalent to 23x≡1(mod7) 
How i did it is simple
 -11x≡5(mod3) means 3|(-11x-5) 
so 3|(11x+5)
 we know 3|6 so 3|(11x+5-6) 
so 3|(11x-1) which means 11x≡1(mod3)

sorry i forgot about your question CRT-
so for ex- we have 23x≡1(mod7) means 7|(23x-1) or 7|(21x+2x-1) so 7|(2x-1)
Now if 7|(2x-1) means 7|4(2x-1) or 7|(8x-4) or 7|(7x+x-4) so 7|(x-4) or we can write it as x≡4(mod 7)